# NullPointerException при подключении

Tags: java, android, исключения

Я думаю, что излишне будет писать код активити. Класс был успешно испытан на консоли Java.

**Листинг:**

```
public class ConnectorZabbix {

    public String goIntoZabbix(String postJsonFile) throws IOException {

        // METHOD NEED GSON-FILE OF TYPE STRING

        URL url = null;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        DataInputStream input;
        DataOutputStream output = null;
        String response = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(LoginActivity.zabbixServerUrl.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        try {
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        httpURLConnection.connect();

        output = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());

        output.writeBytes(postJsonFile);
        output.flush();
        output.close();

        input = new DataInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());


        if (null != (response = input.readUTF())) {
            boolean asfasf = false;
        }

        input.close();

        return response;
    }


}
```

---

**Логи на месте ошибки:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myzabbix.zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.zabbixapiimplementation, PID: 1777
    Theme: themes:{}
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.net.URLConnection java.net.URL.openConnection()' on a null object reference
    at myzabbix.zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.zabbixapiimplementation.objects.ConnectorZabbix.goIntoZabbix(ConnectorZabbix.java:34)
    at myzabbix.zaynukov.sadrutdin.com.zabbixapiimplementation.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:57)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

**Ошибку показывает здесь:**

```
httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

---

**В манифест был добавлен:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: url = null. Неизвестно, каким образом получается ваша zabixServerUrl, но вы должны знать, что активити не на переднем плане не выполняется и все ее виджеты не инициализированы. Вообще обращение к активити подобным образом - дурной тон, который как правило не работает. Передавайте значения из активити через аргументы конструктора, например. Определенно сказать нельзя, так как вы думаете, что данная информация излишняя.  Так же в андроид обращения к сети должны выполняться не в основном потоке (видимо это будет следующей проблемой). А вот информация о используемой IDE как раз излишняя в вопросе.

Comment: Это не помогло. Я переписал отдельно в активити тот метод, сделав его приватным, но ошибку выдаёт тут:
`try {
            url = new URL(LoginActivity.zabbixServerUrl.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("Здесь!", "1", e);
        }
`

Comment: могу только повторить, что нельзя обращаться к полям активити таким образом, как это делаете вы. Вообще нельзя обращаться ни к стаическим полям активити из другого класса ни создавать ее экземпляры самостоятельно. О каком приватном методе вообще идет речь, вы обращаетесь напрямую к какому то полю класса активити. Оно вообще какое то значение принимает, эта ваша конструкция `LoginActivity.zabbixServerUrl.toString()`? MalformedURLException значит, что вашу строку нельзя преобразовать в валидный URL